# Loading QImages from memory at start up

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to load about 450 frames at startup, then at each loop of my application, I want to load the image from the memory, not from the SDCard because it is very flow ~40ms.

I tried the following code, but I get a null image. The images that I want to load are Grey-Scaled images, 1280*960pixels.

I use the following code:

```
        QImage  images[450];

        for (int i=1; i<450;i++)
        {

            sprintf( imFName, "%s/img_%08i.png", imPath.c_str(), i );
            images[i].load(QString(imFName));
            images[i].setColorCount(1);

        }

     for ( int frameIdx = 1;  frameIdx <= 450;  frameIdx++ )
        {
            prevImg = curImg;
            imIndex++;
            printf(" FrameIdx : %d\n", imIndex); fflush(stdout);
            sprintf( imFName, "%s/img_%08i.png", imPath.c_str(), imIndex );

            double t10 = omp_get_wtime();
            QImage curImg;
            bool result = curImg.loadFromData((unsigned char*)images[frameIdx].constBits(),images[frameIdx].byteCount());
            fprintf(stderr, "result %", result);
             if ( curImg.isNull() )
               break;
        }
```

Comment: and the error is most likely in the code you didn't post, since it should work fine. Did you check buffer overflows?

Comment: Is there a good reason you can't just write `QImage curImg = images[frameIdx];`?

Comment: @BЈовић Result gives SetColorCount  Image NULL

Comment: @DanMilburn so it is possible to load images like that ? I don't have to loadfromData? will give it a try

Comment: The image is already loaded, you are just making a (shallow) copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At quick look at your code, I can say that:

- Insted of `QImage images[450];` better to use some sort of containers (STL's `vector` or Qt's `QVector`)
- `QImage images[450];` -- with indexing from `0` to `449` and your cycle `for (int i=1; i<450;i++)` miss `images[0]`.
- Insted of using `sprintf`, use Qt's strings `QString` with its methods for formatting.
- Here you try to access 450's `for ( int frameIdx = 1;  frameIdx <= 450;  frameIdx++ )`
- ...

Your code if full of errors. 
Try to rewrite it.

Make a decision -- write in Qt with its classes, containers and so on; or write in C++ with minimal using of Qt (for handling some special types).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

By the way it's not how [loadFromData](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#loadFromData) works. Load from data expects the same image data format as it would be in a file on disk (png or jpeg etc)
To make that kind of copy from existing data (if you ever need to) you should use something like the following:

```
QImage construct( unsigned char* data, int width, int height, Image::Format format )
{
  return QImage(data, width, height, format);
}
```

In your case you should use a copy assignment